# remove empty lines from text file with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, text-files, lines

I know that I can use:

```
gc c:\FileWithEmptyLines.txt | where {$_ -ne ""} > c:\FileWithNoEmptyLines.txt
```

to remove empty lines. But How I can remove them with '-replace' ?

Comment: Why do you want to replace? And work on your acceptance  rate

Comment: My answer removes empty lines with the `-replace` [comparison operator](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd315321.aspx). `Get-Content` doesn't have a replace parameter, so I'm assuming you're looking for a way to do it with the operator.

Answer (score 80):

I found a nice one liner here >> http://www.pixelchef.net/remove-empty-lines-file-powershell. Just tested it out with several blanks lines including newlines only as well as lines with just spaces, just tabs, and combinations.

```
(gc file.txt) | ? {$_.trim() -ne "" } | set-content file.txt
```

See the original for some notes about the code. Nice :)

Comment: I think on balance I prefer `(gc file.txt) | ? { -not $_.IsNullOrWhiteSpace() } | set-content file.txt` because it expresses the intent more clearly, but it amounts to the same thing.

Comment: On brief glance, I do not seem to have the "IsNullOrWhiteSpace()" method on my strings...and...how could an instance method check for null? The posted answer works great though!

Comment: The IsNullOrWhiteSpace is a static method from System.String object the proper way to call it in PowerShell is as follow : `[String]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace({your string})`. The correct command line base on Neil Barnwell comment is as follow:
 `(gc file.txt) | ? { -not [String]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($_) } | set-content file.txt`

Answer (score 25):

This piece of code from Randy Skretka is working fine for me, but I had the problem, that I still had a newline at the end of the file.

> `(gc file.txt) | ? {$_.trim() -ne "" } | set-content file.txt`

So I added finally this:

```
$content = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllText("file.txt")
$content = $content.Trim()
[System.IO.File]::WriteAllText("file.txt", $content)
```

Answer (score 9):

You can use -match instead -eq if you also want to exclude files that only contain whitespace characters:

```
@(gc c:\FileWithEmptyLines.txt) -match '\S'  | out-file c:\FileWithNoEmptyLines
```

Answer (score 6):

Not specifically using `-replace`, but you get the same effect parsing the content using `-notmatch` and regex.

```
(get-content 'c:\FileWithEmptyLines.txt') -notmatch '^\s*$' > c:\FileWithNoEmptyLines.txt
```

Comment: This worked like charm. I was attempting to remove VB6 comments from a file and this was the final command I used - `(Get-Content -Path ".\vbXML.cls") -replace "\'.*$", "" -notmatch "^\s*$" | Out-File ".\vbXML.uncommented.cls" -Append`

Answer (score 3):

To resolve this with RegEx, you need to use the multiline flag (?m):

```
((Get-Content file.txt -Raw) -replace "(?m)^\s*`r`n",'').trim() | Set-Content file.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do replacing, you have to replace SOMETHING with SOMETHING, and you neither have both.

Comment: is the Poowershell support -remove "" to remove emply lines?

Comment: No it's seems that it does not have support of "-remove".

Comment: You're talking apples and oranges. Remove and Replace are clearly different. What you have will basically work, but perhaps you are trying to rebuild the existing file but without the blanks.

PS C:\> $text=get-content a.txt
PS C:\> $text | where {$_} | out-file a.txt

Answer (score 1):

```
(Get-Content c:\FileWithEmptyLines.txt) | 
    Foreach { $_ -Replace  "Old content", " New content" } | 
    Set-Content c:\FileWithEmptyLines.txt;
```

Answer (score 1):

This removes trailing whitespace and blank lines from file.txt

```
PS C:\Users\> (gc file.txt) | Foreach {$_.TrimEnd()} | where {$_ -ne ""} | Set-Content file.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

If you actually want to filter blank lines from a file then you may try this:

(gc $source_file).Trim() | ? {$_.Length -gt 0}

Answer (score 1):

> file
>
> PS /home/edward/Desktop> `Get-Content ./copy.txt`
>
> [Desktop Entry]
>
> Name=calibre
>   Exec=~/Apps/calibre/calibre
>
> Icon=~/Apps/calibre/resources/content-server/calibre.png
>
> Type=Application*

---

Start by get the content from file and trim the white spaces if any found in each line of the text document. That becomes the object passed to the where-object to go through the array looking at each member of the array with string length greater then 0. That object is passed to replace the content of the file you started with. It would probably be better to make a new file... 
Last thing to do is reads back the newly made file's content and see your awesomeness.

> `(Get-Content ./copy.txt).Trim() | Where-Object{$_.length -gt 0} | Set-Content ./copy.txt`
>
> `Get-Content ./copy.txt`

Comment: >to fix the wrongness of ~/ path to the full path as this file should have here is a bonus 
`(Get-Content ./copy.txt).Replace("~/","/home/edward/") | Set-Content ./copy.txt`

Answer (score 0):

This will remove empty lines or lines with only whitespace characters (tabs/spaces).

```
[IO.File]::ReadAllText("FileWithEmptyLines.txt") -replace '\s+\r\n+', "`r`n" | Out-File "c:\FileWithNoEmptyLines.txt"
```

Answer (score 0):

Get-Content returns immutable array of rows. You can covert this to mutable  array and delete neccessary lines by index.Particular indexex you can get with  match. After that you can write result to new file with Set-Content. With this approach you can avoid empty lines that powershell replace tool leaves when you try to replace smthing with "". Note that I dont guarantee perfect perfomance. Im not a professional powershell developer))

```
$fileLines = Get-Content $filePath
$neccessaryLine = Select-String -Path  $filePath -Pattern 'something'
if (-Not $neccessaryLine) { exit }
$neccessaryLineIndex = $neccessaryLine.LineNumber - 1
$updatedFileContent = [System.Collections.ArrayList]::new($fileLines)
$updatedFileContent.RemoveAt($neccessaryLineIndex)
$updatedHostsFileContent.RemoveAt($domainInfoLineIndex - 1)
$updatedHostsFileContent | Set-Content $hostsFilePath
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Set-Content -Path "File.txt" -Value (get-content -Path "File.txt" | Select-String -Pattern '^\s*$' -NotMatch)
```

This works for me, originally got the line from here and added Joel's suggested '^\s*$': [Using PowerShell to remove lines from a text file if it contains a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24326207/using-powershell-to-remove-lines-from-a-text-file-if-it-contains-a-string)