# Delete lines containing specific character in text file

Tags: powershell

How to delete lines containing a specific character in a text file with PowerShell?

Input file example:

```
12314+000000 00000000
20 300 1238238948023
A+A+000000 00000000
20 500 1238238948023
```

Output file example:

```
20 300 1238238948023
20 500 1238238948023
```

So it will delete lines containing `+` or specific characters or words.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest way is to use new file to write data in it:

```
Get-Content "D:\test.txt" | Where-Object {$_ -notmatch '\+'} | Set-Content "D:\out.txt"
```

That will give:

```
20 300 1238238948023
20 500 1238238948023
```

In `out.txt`.

This is used in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24326207/remove-lines-from-text-file-if-it-contains-string-powershell) and [this](https://superuser.com/questions/117650/deleting-entire-lines-in-a-text-file-based-on-a-partial-string-match-with-window#155387)