# Powershell Trim Space between Sentences

Tags: string, powershell, trim

I'm using Powershell to trim spaces between strings, I need help. I'm reading the values into a variable using Get-Content

Here is my input data:

```
04:31 Alex M.O.R.P.H. & Natalie Gioia - My Heaven http://goo.gl/rMOa2q
[ARMADA MUSIC]

12:37 Chakra - Home (Alexander Popov Remix) http://goo.gl/3janGY
[SOUNDPIERCING]
```

See the space between the two songs? I want to eliminate these. so that the output is:

```
04:31 Alex M.O.R.P.H. & Natalie Gioia - My Heaven http://goo.gl/rMOa2q
[ARMADA MUSIC]
12:37 Chakra - Home (Alexander Popov Remix) http://goo.gl/3janGY
[SOUNDPIERCING]
```

Comment: Eliminate one of the carriage return when two are found back-to-back.

Comment: @PlamZ - How would I write it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [remove empty lines from text file with PowerShell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9223460/remove-empty-lines-from-text-file-with-powershell)

Comment: I am not very competent syntax wise, but be sure to iterate through the text buffer and validate when two carriage return are found in two adjacent cells. Once you've done that, just apply an offset to the rest of the buffer and start again, in case there would be more than one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put the contents in a file called foo.txt.

```
foreach ($line in get-content foo.txt) {
   if ($line -ne '') {
      $line
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it's not madatory but, could I do this with trim? I'm just wondering.

Comment: I don't know... you should try it for yourself and see what happens! The cost of failure is pretty low here.

Answer (score 0):

```
$noEmptyLines = Get-Content -Path C:\FilePath\File.Txt | Where-Object{$_ -notmatch "^\s*$"}
```

You would have a variable where any lines that contained only whitespace would be removed.