# Remove empty rows from csv in powershell

Tags: powershell, csv

I got a csv file that contains some empty rows between the headers and other rows. For example:

```
Headers-----------------------------
Empty Rows------------A-------------
Empty Rows------------B-------------
Empty Rows------------C-------------
Data--------------------------------
Data--------------------------------
```

How to remove those empty rows (A,B and C) from CSV file using powershell?

I thought this would be an easy Google search but I can only find something like "remove lines from text file".

Comment: Which doesn't apply for what reason? A CSV file is a text file. As such solutions from e.g. [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9223460/remove-empty-lines-from-text-file-with-powershell) question are solutions to this one.

Comment: @Seth I did not realise that they are the esame thing, I'll try that.

Comment: You can open it in your text editor of choice and can read all the information within it without (major) problems. So it's a text file in comparison to a binary file which would look really wicked. Though it might be hard to interpret whatever is in that text file.