# How do I delete a line from a text file in powershell?

Tags: powershell

Suddenly I have the urge to finally get into powershell. Right now I have a way to import a text file, create a text file, and add to a file, but is there a way to delete elements from a file? For example if I have a text file:

**test.txt**

```
Quick
Brown
Fox
```

I can import the file with 
$textFile = Get-Content -Path ".\test.txt"

and I can print each element and add them to a new file with

```
foreach($line in $textFile)
{
    Write-Host $line
    Add-Content -Path ".\output.txt" -Value $line
}
```

But how can I delete or remove an element (a line) from the `test.txt` file? I googled for a solution but I only get results for conditions in which someone wants to [delete a blank line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9223460/remove-empty-lines-from-text-file-with-powershell), [deleting the entire file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/remove-item?view=powershell-7), or [how to do it in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/668907/how-to-delete-a-line-from-a-text-file-in-c). I thought it would be as intuitive as the previous commands..

Thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take [this thread](https://superuser.com/questions/117650/deleting-entire-lines-in-a-text-file-based-on-a-partial-string-match-with-window) as an example, it deletes lines by reserving lines which doesn't contains specific content.

You can do the same thing by reserving the line you don't want to delete.

```
Get-Content .\text.txt | Where-Object {$_ -notmatch 'the-word-in-specific-line'} | Set-Content out.txt
```

So, if you want to delete the line containing the string `Brown`:

```
Get-Content .\test.txt | Where-Object {$_ -notmatch 'Brown'} | Set-Content out.txt
```

Comment: This method is iffy for me. Sometime it works, other times its like powershell just completely ignores it.

Comment: Can you describe in what situation it doesn't work?

Comment: Powershell just seems to ignore the part the " Where-Object {$_ -notmatch 'Brown'} " part and just copies over the entire thing

Comment: @pctopgs It would be appreciated if you can provide the file you want to delete lines from and also the specific script you used.

Comment: Works well for me, as long as the search string does not contain parentheses – which I do not understand. It is a single-quoted string, so why is it parsed? The following fails:     Get-Content .\prefs.js | Where-Object {$_ -notmatch 'user_pref("calendar.registry.'} | Set-Content prefs.js

Comment: -match and -notmatch expect a regular expression.