# delete empty rows at end of the csv file using Powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I need to delete the empty rows at end of the CSV file using Powershell. I tried the below code
This code only working to remove the line 7 and 8 in the below sample file image. But I need to delete rows 3,4,5,6,7 and 8. Only row 2 has data.  Any suggestion would be appreciated. thank you.

[image]

```
$content = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllText("PPC.csv")
$content = $content.Trim()
[System.IO.File]::WriteAllText("PPC_1.csv", $content)
```

Comment: Could you tell us why aren't you using `Import-Csv`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There were two sources that helped me out, [Powershell - remove blank/empty rows from CSV file](https://geekdudes.wordpress.com/2020/12/11/powershell-remove-blank-empty-rows-from-csv-file/) and [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9223460/remove-empty-lines-from-text-file-with-powershell) to remove empty lines from text file.

```
Get-Content "test.csv" | Where { $_.Replace(",","").trim() -ne "" } | Out-File trimmed.csv
```

To be fair, this line assumes that you're always going to have commas as your separator and that a line consisting only of commas and whitespace would be considered empty. I hope this helps! I recommend looking at those links.

Answer (score 0):

An [`Import-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-csv)/[`Export-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-csv) version which gives you more control over delimiters and (empty) quoted strings (as: `"","",""`):

```
Import-Csv .\Input.csv |Where-Object { $_.PSObject.Properties.Value -ne '' } |Export-Csv .\Output.Csv
```