# Delete empty rows in multiple csv files by using Powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

To delete empty rows in multiple CSV files by using Powershell. this is the code I am trying with for each loop. But it is writing empty files. The resulting file should open in excel and notepad++ with proper format.

```
Get-ChildItem $paramDest -Filter *Test*.csv | ForEach-Object {
$content = Get-Content $_.FullName | Where { $_.Replace("","","").trim() -ne "" }
Out-File -InputObject $content -FilePath $_.FullName
}
```

[image]

I have some other set of files, the code should work for both these kinds of files. I am okay to have 2 separate codes for these 2 separate files.

Here another file sample format

[image]

Comment: `where { $_.Replace('","','').trim('"') -ne '' }`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [delete empty rows at end of the csv file using Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68454005/1701026)

Answer (score 1):

Try with this

**Input**

[image]

**Command**

```
Import-Csv -Path "C:\sample.csv" | Where-Object { $_.PSObject.Properties.Value -ne '' } | Export-Csv -Path "C:\Sample_clean.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

******Output*******

[image]

**Edit: To update Multiple files, thanks to @Santiago Squarzon**

```
Get-ChildItem $paramDest -Filter *Test*.csv | 
Foreach-Object { 

# get the content of file
$content = Get-Content $_.FullName 

# replace all "," with empty string and exclude those lines and save the output to original file
$content  | where { $_.Replace('","','').trim('"') -ne '' } | Set-Content $_.FullName 
}
```

Comment: I have multiple files, tried the below code, not working as expected 
$paramDest = "C:\Test\"
Get-ChildItem $paramDest -Filter *.csv | ForEach-Object {
Import-Csv -Path $_.FullName | Where-Object { $_.PSObject.Properties.Value -ne '' } | Export-Csv -Path $_.FullName -NoTypeInformation
}

Comment: Do you want to run this line for many file? this sample is for a file and it works perfectly

Comment: @user10260125 updated the solution for multiple files